# Is there a Fermat-era proof of Theorem 69 from Dickson's Intro to NT?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, quadratic-forms

In Dickson’s *Introduction to the Theory of Numbers* (Ch. VI, pp. 91-93), he gives the following [wonderful and wonderfully general] theorem.

> **Theorem 69:** All integral solutions of
>   $$x^2-my^2=zw$$
>   are given by
>   \begin{align}
> x &= \pm \rho(e\xi u+f\eta u-f\xi v-g\eta v),
> & y &= \rho(\xi v+\eta u),  \\
> z &= \rho(e\xi^2+2f\xi\eta+g\eta^2),
> & w &= \rho(eu^2-2fuv+gv^2),
> \end{align}
>   where $\rho,\xi,\eta,u,v$ are arbitrary integers, while $e,f,g$ take only the finite set of integral values such that the forms
>   $$F(\xi,\eta)=e\xi^2+2f\xi\eta+g\eta^2$$
>   are representative forms, just one being chosen from each class of forms of determinant
>   $$f^2-eg=m.$$

Dickson gives several examples (including $m=-1$), and his proof is remarkably elementary (*n.b.* Dickson developed several proofs over the years, in increasingly elementary terms.)…

But I would offer that the proof is not quite “Fermat-era”: I highly doubt Fermat thought about “representative forms” or “class[es] of forms of [a] determinant”.

So here's my

> **QUESTION:** Does Theorem 69 have a proof using only Fermat-era math, either in the general case, or in the specific cases that Fermat is known to have played around with regularly (*i.e.,* $m=-1$, $m=-2$, and $m=-3$)? For instance, how could Fermat have proven that, given
>   $$a^2+b^2=(c^2+d^2)e, \qquad a,b,c,d,e \in \mathbb{Z}$$
>   you can always find integers $e_1$ and $e_2$ such that $e=e_1^2+e_2^2$ and [up to sign]
>   $$(a,b)=(ce_1 \pm de_2, ce_2 \mp de_1)  \tag{$\star$}$$
>   holds?

I know Fermat claimed to have a proof (by infinite descent) of the *existence* of the form $e=e_1^2+e_2^2$, and have seen proofs of that fact using only Fermat-era math.

But what about the implication/form given by ($\star$)? Is there a proof that you can always find integers $e_1$ and $e_2$ that satisfy, using only Fermat-era math?

Comment: For solutions to many equations you can use different combinations.  http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1098490_a_variation_of_the_same_identity   http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1056199_general_pell_equation   http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1053530_another_solution_almost_pythagoras_3   http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1053462_another_solution_almost_pythagoras

Comment: Such variants and combinations can offer a lot.  This decomposition helps to solve other equations. Therefore, always choose such representation which is necessary for a specific task.

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by "implication/form given by (*)" Euler [proved](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_of_Fermat%27s_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares#Euler.27s_proof_by_infinite_descent) that e will be of the same form if gcd(a,b) = 1 (Proposition 4). Is this what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In his *Diophantine Analysis* [pp. 31–33], Carmichael gives a series of lemmas and a final corollary which essentially duplicates Dickson’s theorem in the case $m=-1$. He even goes so far as to say that the result is “due to Fermat”. So it seems that case, at least, already has a Fermat-era proof.

Comment: Fermat often declined to give proofs.  He was a genius but he could get away with it as his income didn't come from math. (He was a town magistrate.)  However I don't think there is an instance of him stating an incorrect result.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting he was stating an incorrect result. I'm putting together a paper, and want to be 100% sure I am using only Fermat-era math.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting that he was stating an incorrect result. I was musing on the thought that there may have been a Fermat-era proof due to Fermat himself, but not written, or lost to us.

Comment: @KierenMacMillan Can you provide a reference (letters, notes of Fermat etc.) where Fermat considers these types of Diophantine Equation? As far as I know, he has considered only Pell Equation (among these types).